# Box-shadow to the bottom of an item in horizontal FlatList

Tags: react-native

I'm implementing a horizontal FlatList and want to add a box-shadow to each item. When I add `elevation` property for each item, it spans on left and right (as FlatList is Horizontal). I want to add box-shadow to the bottom of item also. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: you cab give margin to renderItem View

Comment: Yes there are many ways.